# Move apps between monitors - C#

Tags: c#

I ha a form referenced like:

```
MainForm= Form1;
```

but in another method same class; after detecting that system have more that 1 monitor:

```
int screens = Screen.AllScreens.Length;
if (screens > 1)
{
    model.AddItem((CefMenuCommand)26504, "Switch Screen (Monitor)");
    model.AddSeparator();
}
```

I need to switch between these:

```
Screen[] lsScreen = Screen.AllScreens;
Screen myScreen = Screen.FromControl(MainForm);

if(myScreen == lsScreen[1])
{
    MainForm.Location = lsScreen[0].WorkingArea.Location; // Primary Screen
    MainForm.Top = MainForm.Left = 0;
    MainForm.Width = lsScreen[0].WorkingArea.Width;
    MainForm.Height = lsScreen[0].WorkingArea.Height;
}
else
{
    MainForm.Location = lsScreen[1].WorkingArea.Location; // Secondary Screen
    MainForm.Width = lsScreen[1].WorkingArea.Width;
    MainForm.Height = lsScreen[1].WorkingArea.Height;
}
```

**Update**

this is that Visual Studio 2019 show:

[image]

1. works partially correct; since I can move the application from the primary screen to the secondary one; the problem is that I can't move from the secondary screen to the primary one (Return); It seems to me that the error is in the last piece of code, that I cannot determine what it is.
2. the other limitation is that it only works between two screens; primary and secondary; How can I adapt my code to improve it so that it supports an indeterminate number of screen ...

Comment: Psychic debugging required.  Perhaps this method gets called more than once, common mishap when subscribing an event.  Set a breakpoint.

Comment: the method is only called once. so add this line of code (CefMenuCommand) 26504, "Switch Screen (Monitor) that actually triggers the function.

Comment: @HansPassant I think the comparison in the IF is not adequate ... `if(myScreen == lsScreen[1])`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution of the first question:**

replace this:

```
if(myScreen == lsScreen[1])
```

with this:

```
if(myScreen.DeviceName == lsScreen[1].DeviceName)
```

**Pending Improvement / Second question.**

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code from an app I wrote that dynamically populates a ContextMenuStrip with all the other monitors that something can be sent to.  It might give you some ideas on how to approach this:

```
Private Sub ContextMenuStrip1_Opening(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles ContextMenuStrip1.Opening
    If Screen.AllScreens.Count > 1 Then
        SendToToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Clear()
        SendToToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
        Dim containingScreen As Screen = Screen.FromHandle(Me.Handle)
        For i As Integer = 0 To Screen.AllScreens.Count - 1
            Dim curScreen As Screen = Screen.AllScreens.ElementAt(i)
            If curScreen.DeviceName <> containingScreen.DeviceName Then
                Dim screenMenu As New ToolStripMenuItem(curScreen.DeviceName)
                screenMenu.Tag = i
                AddHandler screenMenu.Click, AddressOf ScreenMenu_Click
                SendToToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(screenMenu)
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ScreenMenu_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim screenMenu As ToolStripMenuItem = DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem)
    Dim index As Integer = screenMenu.Tag
    Me.SendToScreen(index)
End Sub

Public Sub SendToScreen(ByVal index As Integer)
    If index < 0 OrElse index > (Screen.AllScreens.Count - 1) Then
        index = 0
    End If

    Dim curScreen As Screen = Screen.FromHandle(Me.Handle)
    Dim destScreen As Screen = Screen.AllScreens.ElementAt(index)

    Dim ptF As New PointF((CDbl(Me.Location.X) - curScreen.Bounds.Left) / curScreen.Bounds.Width,
                          (CDbl(Me.Location.Y) - curScreen.Bounds.Top) / curScreen.Bounds.Height)
    Dim szF As New PointF(CDbl(Me.Width) / curScreen.Bounds.Width,
                          CDbl(Me.Height) / curScreen.Bounds.Height)

    Dim destPt As New Point(destScreen.Bounds.Left + ptF.X * destScreen.Bounds.Width,
                            destScreen.Bounds.Top + ptF.Y * destScreen.Bounds.Height)
    Dim destSz As New Size(destScreen.Bounds.Width * szF.X, destScreen.Bounds.Height * szF.Y)

    Me.Location = destPt
    Me.Size = destSz
End Sub
```

Here's what it looks like when the menu is displayed on my system with three monitors (sometimes I have four total connected and it works great then, too):

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution, it would be good to take advantage of multiple monitors. I see that it is not in C # I will do the implementation as soon as I have time, since I will have to convert the code and verify that everything goes well.

Comment: @idle-mind the other problem I see is that as you indicate it is done through a ContextMenuStrip; I also need to adapt it to work with CefMenu cefsharp ...

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  My favorite language is VB.Net.  I do a lot of work in C#, too, but this particular project is a personal one, so I wrote it in VB.

Comment: I've never worked with "CefMenu cefsharp".  Key points in my code...the `Opening` event fires before the menu is displayed.  It's there that I enumerate the monitors and add a submenu for each monitor that is not the one containing my form.  The Index number of the screen is stored in the `.Tag` property of the submenu so it can be used in the `Click` event and eventually `SendToScreen()`.